# PostgreSQL - Query a table that stores value changes and present output in a periodic format

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table that stores value changes of a variable:

```
Timestamp    Value
13:14        12
14:25        33
15:13        24
15:41        48
16:31        54
17:00        63
19:30        82
22:30        13
```

I need to construct a query that outputs the following:

```
Timestamp    Value
14:00        12
15:00        33
16:00        48
17:00        63
18:00        63
19:00        63
20:00        82
21:00        82
22:00        82
23:00        13
And so on...
```

What would be the correct approach to achieve the desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use date_trunc() and date/time operator

roundup example

```
user=# select datetime from tbl_test limit 1;
        datetime
------------------------
 2013-07-26 15:36:00+09
(1 row)

user=# select date_trunc('hour', datetime) + interval '1 hour'
       from tbl_test limit 1
        ?column?
------------------------
 2013-07-26 16:00:00+09
(1 row)
```

formatting example

```
user=# select to_char(date_trunc('hour', datetime) + interval '1 hour', 'HH24:MI')
              from tbl_test limit 1;
 to_char
---------
 16:00
(1 row)
```

UPDATED:
you can select latest one using window function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.timestamp, last_value(x.value) OVER (PARTITION BY x.timestamp)
FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 hour', 'HH24:MI') AS timestamp, value 
      FROM tbl_test) as x
ORDER BY x.timestamp;
```

postgresql reference:

1. [9.9. Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)
2. [9.8. Data Type Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer EveryEvery. That helps me a little, however this will only truncate the minutes and add one hour to the result, still not the desired output: I need to append absent hours (like 20:00, 21:00, 22:00, etc) and if there are two or more values in the same hour period I'd need to choose the latest. Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bd985/5.

Comment: @Francisco i misunderstood your question. i add some code to  select latest one from duplication. however, it can't add absent hour's value. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bd985/22/0

Comment: @Francisco when you get a good solution, plz post your answer. I like to know good solution. :-) Usually, I have solved these kind of problems using other script language like python.